# There is not javacard.framework in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javacard

I tried to write a javacard applet. So,

1. Download Java Card Classic Development Kit 3.0.4 that I get its JAR File
2. I add the JAR File in to Eclipse by add it in the Java Build Path>Library.

But when I wanted to import javacard.framework, I got the **"javacard.framework cannot be resolved"** error. Moreover, when I saw inside the Development Kit, there was no javacard.framwork package in it.

How do I make the "javacard.framework" package exist?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the JAR [java_card_kit-classic-3_0_4-rr-bin-do-b28-windows-06_sep_2011.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javacard/download/devkit/index.html)

It is a self-extracting archive with included installer. Just execute it and install the Java Card Development Kit somewhere on your hard disk.

Comment: I extract the JAR file but I cannot file the installer in it. There is only the folder of many java package such as "com.","net.","apache."

Comment: Just execute the JAR `java -jar java_card_kit-classic-3_0_4-rr-bin-do-b28-windows-06_sep_2011.jar`, don't extract anything.